# Proving convergence of a linear combination of sequences

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, convergence-divergence

Suppose $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ are converging sequences. I want to show that the sequence $(c_n)$ defined by $c_n = 3a_n - 7b_n$ also converges.

My attempt:
Suppose $a_n \rightarrow a$ and $b_n\rightarrow b$. Let $\epsilon_1$, $\epsilon_2 > 0$ be arbitrary but fixed. Then there exists integers $N_1$, $N_2\in \mathbb N$ such that
if $n\geq N_1$, then $|a_n - a| < \epsilon_1$ and if $n\geq N_2$, then $|b_n - b| < \epsilon_2$.

Now let $\epsilon > 0$ be arbitrary but fixed. I want to find some $\delta > 0$ and some $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $n\geq N$ implies $|3a_n - 7b_n| < \delta$.
So
\begin{align}
|3a_n - 7b_n| &= |3a_n - 7b_n - 3a + 3a - 7b + 7b| \\ &\leq |3a_n - 3a| + |7b_n - 7b| + |3a + 7b| \\ &= 3|a_n - a| + 7|b_n - b| + |3a+ 7b| \\ &< 3\epsilon_1 + 7\epsilon_2 + |3a+7b|\end{align}
And this is where I'm stuck.

Comment: If you are talking about sequences, you don't want $\delta$, only $N$. So you want to show for any $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $N(\epsilon)$ such that if $n > N(\epsilon)$ then $|(3a_n-7b_n)-(3a-7b)| < \epsilon$. Write this as $|(3(a_n-a)-7(b_n-b)| < \epsilon$ and you are close to being done.

Answer (score 1):

You have some correct ideas but you do not want to show that $|3a_{n}-7b_{n}|<\delta$. This would effectively mean that the limit of $c_{n}$ is zero. Instead what you might guess is that $\lim_{n\to \infty}c_{n} = 3a-7b$. This would be shown if for every $\epsilon >0$ you can find a $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\geq N$
$$|c_{n}-(3a-7b)| = |(3a_{n}-7b_{n}) - (3a-7b)|<\epsilon.$$
Can you take it from here?

PS. It is equally difficult but more useuful prove linearity of limit whenever they exist.